# Move text onto Image CSS/Bootstrap5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I've been trying to get my rows and columns to appear over my background image. I've been struggling with this for a while. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am also quite new to this so, if it is simple I've yet to find it XD

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Testing</title>

    <!--CSS-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b5212ab333.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!--Index Stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    
    
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kQtW33rZJAHjgefvhyyzcGF3C5TFyBQBA13V1RKPf4uH+bwyzQxZ6CmMZHmNBEfJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id="about-us" class="">
          <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x618.png" alt=""></a>

          <div class="container-md">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-4 about-text-header">
                One of two columns
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                One of two columns
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change Image path i have changed image path.
Give a backgroud-image to parent div in css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <!--CSS-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b5212ab333.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--Index Stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kQtW33rZJAHjgefvhyyzcGF3C5TFyBQBA13V1RKPf4uH+bwyzQxZ6CmMZHmNBEfJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #about-us{
        background-image: url('https://previews.123rf.com/images/melpomen/melpomen1904/melpomen190400312/120268255-e-learning-concept-with-person-using-a-laptop-on-a-white-table.jpg?fj=1');
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="https://placeholder.com">
      <div id="about-us" class="p-5">
          <div class="container-md">
            <div class="row justify-content-center" style=" position: relative;">
              <div class="col-4 text-light about-text-header">
                First Column
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 text-light ">
                Second Column
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put image as background for your block using CSS. Inside your style.css file:

```css
    #about-us {
      background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/1920x618.png');
    }
```

There are also CSS properties to set background image position, size etc.
You can find more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)

Edit: According to you comment if you want to achieve [this design](https://gyazo.com/adc1089774dc1e885e526e23f997cff4):

HTML:

```
<body>
  
  <!--  Top image GTA, there is no text so it can be <img> tag -->
  <div id="hero-img">
      <img src="./yourimg.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <!--  About us section, with car in background -->
  <div id="about-us">

      <!--  Your regular columns and content -->
      <div class="container-md">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-4 about-text-header">
            One of two columns
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            One of two columns
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
    #hero-img{
      /* to remove space between images, because car image has this wave and page background would be visable  */
      margin-bottom: -50px;
    }

    #hero-img img{
      object-fit: cover;
      width: 100%
      height: 600px;
    }

    #about-us{
      background-image: url('./yourCarImage.png');
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      /* probably padding needed */
      padding: 100px 0;
    }
```

This should work in general, adjust it for your needs.

Comment: I was hoping more to put text position as this section is to be below a carousel; so I was hoping to move the text up and have it change and move. Would the background properties allow this?

Comment: @Welshy1235 I am not sure what do you mean, but background-image position is bounded to #about-us element (or any other you use it on), you can only manipulate background position or size within this element. If you need more help try to describe it better, or provide few screenshots. Simple paint visualisation can help too

Comment: I was mainly referring to moving text down responsively to stay in place. Would margin be best for this?

Comment: @Welshy1235 "moving text down responsively to stay in place" - this is not specific, i can't tell what do you need exactly. Maybe if you could add CSS to your example here in questin so we can see it. Take `style.css` code and paste it in `<style> /* styles */ </style>` in HTML `<head></head>`.

Comment: Like this: https://gyazo.com/adc1089774dc1e885e526e23f997cff4?token=3f5f6db609df094a101ef2682f5e081e

Where the background image is separate and the foreground image will have the text.

Comment: @Welshy1235 i have edited my answer, i hope this solves your problem